# How can I downgrade to a lower version of PostgreSQL on OSX

Tags: postgresql

I'm working on an app that is only compatible with postgreSQL 9.4.5 and my current version is 9.5.2

Is there any way to download the older version? I can't seem to find it.

I found older versions here but they're meant for Solaris.

Comment: Did postgersql 9.5 have any major backward incompatible changes? I didn't notice any (though I didn't read id meticulously) http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/release-9-5.html

Answer (score 0):

The answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/31261608/1949363 describes in great detail how to do a downgrade. Does it work for you?

In terms downloading old versions, 9.4 is available on `brew`

`$ brew search postgresql@9.4
postgresql@9.4`